# create AAC file from raw data using Media Foundation

Tags: c++, audio, ms-media-foundation

I have raw audio data and I want to create a corresponding aac/m4a/mp4 file using Media Foundation.

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd742785(v=vs.85).aspx) article describes all the settings and configurations.

I wonder if there is an example code or tutorial that shows how to do that?

I found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819476(v=vs.85).aspx) tutorial, but unfortunately, this is not **raw data to mp4 file**, but  mp4 to another mp4 tutorial (changing the properties of an already existing file).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AAC file is basically the file with raw data. You don't need API to create such file, just write the data using file I/O functions. There is a delicate aspect about things like ADTS headers, but in general it is as simple as that.

With Media Foundation you can produce MP4 files, and most suitable API for that is [Sink Writer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819489). Apparently, raw data alone is insufficient to produce as you have to provide additional mandatory information, such as at the very least basic properties of the encoding. Once you are through with this, you write your AAC data in chunks and the API formats it as an MP4/M4A file. I am not aware of a tutorial which does exactly this, but it's a pretty straightforward use of the API.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Roman. It seems that Sink Writer is what I need now. I will start working on that.